# How can I re-use a model in multiple namespaces without redefining it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restplus

Does the `flask_restplus` library allows to define a model once and re-use it in multiple namespaces. In my use case, I would like to have a general model for returning on successful post requests. At the moment, I have to redefine the model in every namespace.

**API with two namespaces**

```py
from flask_restplus import Api

from api_service.api.api_1 import api as ns_1
from api_service.api.api_2 import api as ns_2

api = Api()


api.add_namespace(ns_1, path='/api_1')
api.add_namespace(ns_2, path='/api_2')
```

**Code snippet, I have to redefine in every namespace**

```py
post_response_model = api.model("Post response", {
    'message': fields.String(),
    'id': fields.String(description="Id of inserted entry")
})
```

Comment: Does it work? If yes, then you can do that.

Comment: It only works if I add the snippet in every namespace. 'api.model' has to be the namespace object. I would like to prevent this(DRY).